# How do I create a pie chart in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart that displays percentages. How do I create a pie chart using JFrame in Java?

This is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PieChart extends JFrame{


private int Midterm;
private int Quizzes;
private int Projects;
private int Final;

public PieChart(){
    setPercentage();

}
private void setPercentage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
//construct a pie chart with percentages
public PieChart(int Midterm, int Quizzes, int Final, int Projects){
this.Midterm = Midterm;
this.Quizzes = Quizzes;
this.Final = Final;
this.Projects = Projects;
}
//return midterm
public int getMidterm(){
    return Midterm;

}
//public void setMidterm(int Midterm){
    //this.Midterm = Midterm;
    //repaint();

//}
//return Quizzes
public int getQuizzes(){
    return Quizzes;

}
public int Final(){
    return Final;
}
public int Projects(){
    return Projects;

}
//draw the circle
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);

}
//initialize circle parameters
int circleRadius = 
    (int)(Math.min(getWidth(),getHeight())* 0.4);
int xCenter= getWidth()/2;
int yCenter = getHeight()/2;

}
```

Comment: Maybe you could rephrase this as a question.

Comment: What's your plan for doing this? What have you tried so far? Where have you run into problems?

Comment: I have to make a testPie chart to run it i think.

Comment: You people are too overzealous with the closing.  The OP was trying to improve the question.

Comment: ok so I cant get any help now? don't want the answer just a point in the right direction

Comment: @JavaD: two people have requested that this question be reopened. If three more people do the same, answers will be allowed on this question again.

Comment: reopened, not the best question but could be made worthwhile with some editing

Answer (score 2):

to draw pie chart you should use fillArc(x,y,width,height,starting angle,arc angle)

draw different arcs related to each other (1st i.e left side arc must be same as right side of previous arc)

you have to make your own logic for setting starting angle...

like

suppose u have total 12 products and u want to draw pie-chart for them (sale)

total of 12 product's sale  =  1200

individual product sale a = 120, b = 0, c = 500,.....

angle for individual product a = (120*360)/1200  b = 0   c = (500*360)/

and then set relative arc angle

i think so this will give u your pie chart

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to develop it on your own? Or can you use an open source API? Maybe [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) has something you can use.

Comment: yes I have to develop it on my own. I found another code and its working for me. I do not know how to display the percentages though.

Answer (score 0):

In the `paintComponent` method, a [Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object is passed in. With this, you can use `fillArc` to draw the various slices and `drawString` to label them.

Also, I'd suggest that you don't draw directly on the JFrame, but instead do so on a JComponent that you then add to a JFrame.