# Paint different colors on button in android

Tags: java, android, pie-chart

I have a transparent image its a circle style. I want to fill multiple colors to this image.It will look like circle graph. example 20% red color 30% blue remaing 50% black like that. Can any one give idea how to paint colors by using percentage.  And later that image need to rotate like phone dailer.

Comment: [Shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating pie charts programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662984/creating-pie-charts-programmatically)

Comment: So in my guess you want to create pie chart dynamically. If yes then this [tutorial](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/02/pie-chart-in-android.html) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) can generate pie charts and can save the resultant chart to JPEG format. Here is an [example](http://robbamforth.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/java-jfreechart-how-to-save-a-jcfreechart-to-jpeg-file/) of how to do so. Here is a [3D example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartPieChart3DDemo4withacustomlabelgenerator.htm).

There are more examples and documentation available in the developers guide.

Other charting libraries which generate piecharts:

- [Charts4J](http://charts4j.googlecode.com/)
- [EasyCharts (Commercial)](http://www.objectplanet.com/easycharts/)

This one is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662984/creating-pie-charts-programmatically).

Comment: Not exactly am looking, but got some idea, Thank you